# Subsonic 3.0.0.3 with MySQL 4template is not working

Tags: mysql, subsonic3

I am ready and see all the tutorials and videos to configure the subsonic 3.0.0.3 with MySql and fail to genarate the ActiveRecords.cs. I use the MySQL.ttinclude in the folder to generate the class but it is still not working. I rename all the refenreces to SQLServer.ttinclude to MySQL.ttinclude and it still does not work. The error is: Metadata file "MySql.Data" could not by found.

I really need to use the subsonic version 3.0.0.3 with MySql 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.  Make sure you actually run the installer for the MySQL connector as that put everything in the GAC.  I tried to get it to work by just adding the ref to MySql.Data, and I got the same error as you.  Everything worked perfectly once I ran their install.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all reference is setting. The two dlls Subsonic.core.dll and MySql.Data.dll. I think that's probable a bug int the 4templates for MySql. Many people still have problems whit the version for MySql. In the videos of rob for configurin and setting MySQL generate, it still work perfectly, but the files in the pack 3.0.0.3 are different.

Answer (score 0):

dunno if you got same problem but i had trouble and it was because i had a C# project but was using the VB templates and it never created the files, also i have used mysql connector 6.1 if this helps as i think this is the most compatable version when it comes to stuff like this.

Comment: I'am now use the Entity Framework and all works perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Iam using MySQL Connector 6.1 whit provider. Now I try to generate my class with the 4Templates to LINQ, but I don't have success. I see this error in VStudio 2008

*Warning    1   Multiple template directives were found in the template. All but the first one will be ignored. Multiple parameters to the template directive should be specified within one template directive.*

When I try to generate the class with the templates for Active Record, It's works, wonderfull, but I realy need the LINQ templates class generated.